# Blurry text in visual studio community 2015 after activating High Contrast mode

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I was explaining to a friend how you can hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> when you print screen to only capture the active window, and that led to reading about more commands to use (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Print_screen).

So I tried the "Pressing <kbd>Prt Sc</kbd> with both the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and left <kbd>Shift</kbd> pressed turns on a high contrast mode" (**DON'T DO IT**), and since then my visual studio has been acting up:

[image]

[image]

So I accidentally activated high contrast mode, and Visual studio has been weird since. Note that it's the only program that's been affected. Seems to be related to clearType text, but don't know how exactly, disabling it does not fix it.

As you can see, hovering over the blurry text "fixes" it temporary, but when I tab out it randomly returns. It has nothing to do with the work area zoom.

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: I know it sounds dumb but did you try rebooting the machine?

Comment: Of course @MariaInesParnisari I've given up on finding a solution myself, "the accident" occurred some weeks back. Stackoverflow is usually my last resort :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so disabling hardware acceleration seems to have fixed the issue. Leaving instructions here incase you are in need:

[image]